# Login and logout with web.py

Tags: python, session, web.py

I have a little problem with web.py. Exacly I have problem with sessions.

Link to my app:
http://len.iem.pw.edu.pl/~witkowr1/apps/demo/

Login/password: wtq/wtq

Code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import web 
import json
from web.contrib.template import render_jinja
import datetime

prefix = '/~witkowr1/apps/demo'

urls = (
    prefix + '/login','Login',
    prefix + '/logout','Logout',
    prefix + '/', 'Index',
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())
wsgi = app.wsgifunc()
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'),initializer={'time':datetime.datetime.now()})
render = render_jinja('static', encoding = 'utf-8')
render._lookup.globals.update(assets=prefix+'/static')

class Login:
    def GET(self):
    web.seeother(prefix+'/')

    def POST(self):
        login = web.input().login
    password = web.input().passwd
    if login == 'wtq' and password == 'wtq':
            session.logged_in = True
            session.time = datetime.datetime.now()
            last_login = web.cookies().get('time')
            if last_login == None:
                last_login_data = u'ZalogowaĹ‚eĹ› siÄ™ pierwszy raz.'
            else:
                last_login_data = last_login
        return render.logged(name=login, date_last_login=last_login_data)
        else:
            session.logged_in = False
        error=u'Niepoprawne dane. SprĂłbuj jeszcze raz.'
            return render.login(error_msg=error)

class Logout:
    def GET(self):
        web.seeother(prefix+'/')

    def POST(self):
        session.logged_in = False
        web.setcookie('time',session.time)
        message = u'ZostaĹ‚eĹ› poprawnie wylogowany.'
        session.kill()
        return render.login(error_msg=message)

class Index:
    def GET(self):
        return render.login()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I would like to verify session and if I login early, I see site with latest login date.
Now, when I refresh the site, I must login again.
I think, that I check session, when I rendering HTML site, but I don't know, what I do it.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
Very stupid mistakes :)

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import web 
from web.contrib.template import render_jinja
import datetime

prefix = ''

urls = (
    prefix + '/', 'Index',
    prefix + '/login','Login',
    prefix + '/logout','Logout',
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())
wsgi = app.wsgifunc()
web.config.debug = False
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'),initializer={'time':datetime.datetime.now()})
render = render_jinja('static', encoding = 'utf-8')
render._lookup.globals.update(assets=prefix+'/static')

allowed = (
    ('user','user'),
)

class Login:

    def GET(self):
        web.seeother(prefix+'/')

    def POST(self):
        login = web.input().login
        passwd = web.input().passwd
        if(login,passwd) in allowed:
            session.logged_in = True
        session.login = login
            session.time = datetime.datetime.now()
            last_login = web.cookies().get('time')
            if last_login == None:
                last_login_data = u'Zalogowałeś się pierwszy raz.'
            else:
                last_login_data = last_login
            return render.logged(name=login, date_last_login = last_login_data)
        else:
            session.logged_in = False
        error=u'Niepoprawne dane. Spróbuj jeszcze raz.'
            return render.login(error_msg=error)

class Logout:
    def GET(self):
        web.seeother(prefix+'/')

    def POST(self):
        session.logged_in = False
        web.setcookie('time',session.time)
        message = u'Zostałeś poprawnie wylogowany.'
        session.kill()
        return render.login(error_msg=message)

class Index:
    def GET(self):
        if session.get ('logged_in') == True: 
            last_login = web.cookies().get('time')
            if last_login == None:
                last_login_data = u'Zalogowałeś się pierwszy raz.'
            else:
                last_login_data = last_login
            return render.logged(name=session.get ('login'), date_last_login = last_login_data)
    else:
            return render.login()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are not checking whether they are logged in if they access the page with GET method.

You would need to make a change like:

```
def GET(self):
    if session.logged_in:
        last_login = web.cookies().get('time')
        if last_login == None:
            last_login_data = u'ZalogowaĹ‚eĹ› siÄ™ pierwszy raz.'
        else:
            last_login_data = last_login
        return render.logged(name=login, date_last_login=last_login_data)
    else:
        web.seeother(prefix+'/')
```

But you should rewrite this, a lot, so that you are taken to another page once you are logged in, and that page is responsible for rendering this information. There is a lot of room for improvement in the structure of your application.

That said, the simple answer is - even though you store the session, the "GET" method of login is entirely unaware of sessions, and will always return the login prompt.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ;)
I improve my app, but now It don't work. I don't know, where the problem lies. Could You help me?

Code:
[link](http://pastebin.com/n38uMk9M)

Comment: Your code refers several times to `render.logged`, however, I don't see `logged` defined anywhere in the code you provided - should this be referring to something else?

Comment: logged and login are HTML files in another catalog. Check this: pastebin.com/PBGQSTNg and http://pastebin.com/FubhHVL5

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved your problem already but since it looks like there are often some problems with sessions in web.py I pushed a small and crude demo of it to bitbucket. Works fine for me so hope this works for you.

You can get it via:

```
git clone https://victorkohler@bitbucket.org/victorkohler/webpy-login.git
```

Comment: This does not seem to be open to the public, one needs credentials. Please make it publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer to your question but an extension of the question**. I have a similar solution to the login from the webpy cookbook (http://webpy.org/cookbook/userauthbasic) but would like to load the variable allowed from a database.

```
allowed = (
    ('user','user'),
)
```

When I tried a read to assign the value to the variable it comes out as "None" when executed in the login class.

```
def readUsersDb(): 
    def POST(self):
        # load user data into allowed variable
        usersDbFilePath = 'userdata/irf/default/'
        usersDbFile = 'usersDb.db'
        usersDbFilePath = usersDbFilePath + usersDbFile

        conn = sqlite3.connect(usersDbFilePath)
        c = conn.cursor()

        c.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
        output = c.fetchall()
        conn.close()
        global allowed
        allowed = output
readUsersDb()
```

The login functions when the variable allowed is hard coded. I used the format from the database read and it still functions as expected so it is not a format issue.

```
#response: [(u'user1', 'user1'), (u'user2', 'user2'), (u'user3', 'user3')]
```

Hopefully someone has tried to do this previously. If it is a faux pas to add a question as an answer I apologize ahead of time.